# Custom Hashing Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, hash

Out of sheer boredom, I decided to write a hashing algorithm in python. It all works, however I've got a couple problems:

1. Results are similar (e.g. `hash(1234)` has one character difference to `hash(4321)`)
2. There is a repeating sequence forming (more noticeable on smaller inputs)

Most of the values I've used are random, I have no experience writing a hash algorithm but I wanted to give it a shot. Is there anything I can do to resolve the 2 problems I'm having?

```
def mash(n):
    l = [int(x) for x in list(str(n))]
    m = []
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if pow(len(l) >> 1, (i + 1) << 3) % (i + 1) == 0 and i != 0:
            m[-1] = int(str(m[-1]) + str(l[i]))
        else:
            m.append(l[i])
    return m

def hash(content, key=None):
    """Hashes the content (either a string or number"""
    o = [0] * 128
    if type(content) is float:
        while content % 1 != 0:
            content = content * 10
        content = int(content)
    if type(content) is str:
        content = int(''.join([str(ord(x)) for x in list(content)]))
    if type(content) is int:
        content = mash(content)
        _ = []
        for i in range(len(content)):
            _.append((chr(((content[i] * (i << 3)) % 94) + 33)))
            # 33 - 126
        content = ''.join(_)
    elif type(content) is not str:
        raise Exception
    z = [ord(x) for x in list(content)]
    for i in range(len(z)):
        if z[i] % 2 == 0:
            n = next((i for i, x in enumerate(o) if not x and i % 2 == 0), 0)
        else:
            n = next((i for i, x in enumerate(o) if not x and i % 2 == 1), 0)
        o[n] = content[i]
    o = [str(x) for x in o]
    o.reverse()
    init_n = o.count('0')
    while o.count('0') > 5:
        n = next((i for i, x in enumerate(o) if x == '0'), None)
        o[n] = chr(((pow(init_n >> 1, o.count('0'))) % 94) + 33)
    o.reverse()
    return ''.join(o)
```

Note that the `key` parameter has not yet been implemented. Wanted to resolve existing issues before attempting another feature.

Comment: unfortunately, going out of your way to solve these two problems will create problems elsewhere. If it ain't broken, don't fix it.

Comment: While I respect the "If it ain't broke, don't fix it" attitude, progress in life would be incredibly stale. And this isn't my attempt to fix existing algorithms, but rather to learn and maybe one day I'll be able to create a proper algorithm.

Comment: It would help if you gave an explanation in words of your algorithm. Your function seems overly complex, so it would be too slow for non-cryptographic applications, and of course it's highly unlikely to be secure enough for crypto work. BTW, there's no need to do `[int(x) for x in list(str(n))]`, you can iterate directly over strings, so `[int(x) for x in str(n)]` does the same job. Also, the `pow` function can take a modulus as its optional 3rd arg; doing `pow(a, b, m)` is much more efficient than doing  `pow(a, b) % m`.

Comment: Things to learn: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is around four years old at this point, but I still wanted to give an answer to this Stack Overflow post.

Recall with Hash Tables, our goal is "near" constant time searching for data. We have the option of using a binary search tree for a faster O(log n), though it must be stored in sorted order and maintain balance.

We can do better, by using memory for a decent tradeoff in speed! This is a common pattern we see in Computer Science.

Hashing functions are created to convert data of various sizes to a fixed "address" that can be identified with a key. Key features include this algorithm must be done quickly, minimal collisions with existing keys, and repeatable. Collisions will happen so we need a strategy to handle them.

```
class BasicHashTable:
    """ Simple HashTable implementation """
    class HashableItem:
        def __init__(self, key=None, value=None):
            self.key = key
            self.value = value

    def __init__(self):
        self.capacity = 4
        self.size = 2**self.capacity - 1
        self.slot = [None for _ in range(self.size)]
        self.count = 0

    def _hash(self, s):
        i = 1
        hash_value = 0
        for char in string:
            h += ord(char) * i
            i += 1
        return h % self.size
```

Here I have a hashing algorithm that is based on the ordinal value of a character and the position in the string. I also return the value as it is confined within the BasicHashTable size constraint.

Recall that this algorithm fulfills constraint outlined earlier:

- Quick
- Minimal Collisions
- Repeatable

I omitted two key interfaces put and get. Since they can vary and out of the scope of this post. Though, they will handle collisions and resizing the BasicHashTable as it exceeds the capacity.

Cheers!